# Condition put on images

Tags: php, html, image

I want to put a condition on images come from directory that if the images count is 1 then show this div. But the condition is not running properly after applying the condition on it. Please help me to resolve this problem: My code is given below:

```
 <?php

    $id = 115; 
    $path_image = "pageimage/".$id."/";
            if(file_exists($path_image)){ 
            $dir =  dir($path_image);


    //List files in images directory
    while (($file =  $dir->read()) !== false){
   if($file>=1){  
    ?>
    <div id="middleimg" style="background:url(<?php echo $path_image.$file; ?>); background-repeat:no-repeat;">


      <div id="nav">
        <div id="navinner">
          <ul>
            <?php
                                    foreach($pageMenu as $pmenu){
                                    $url = generateURL($pmenu->custom_url, $pmenu->page_friendlyname, $pmenu->page_title, $pmenu->page_id);?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $pmenu->page_name; ?> </a> </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <!--<li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.php">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LOCATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="deliverly.php">DELIVERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPECIAL OFFER</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="banner-containerhome">
        <div id="promoBanner">
          <!--<div id="pizza">-->
          <div id="wowslider-container1">
        <div class="ws_images">
    <span><img src="data1/images/banner.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows0"/></span>
    <span><img src="data1/images/banner.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows0"/></span>
    </div>
    <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
    <a href="#wows0" title=""><img src="data1/tooltips/banner.jpg" alt=""/>1</a>
    <a href="#wows1" title=""><img src="data1/tooltips/chrysanthemum.jpg" alt=""/>2</a>
    </div></div>
        <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>

         <!-- </div>-->

        </div>
          <div class="rightcontents">
          <?php 

     echo $page_content[1]->page_content;

          ?>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }}} ?>
```

Comment: i want when condition is false then the div under the if condition

"<div id="middleimg" style="background:url(<?php echo $path_image.$file; ?>); background-repeat:no-repeat;">"

is not running

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things...

1.- read() reads the directory as an iterator, returning the file name, have you tried to `echo $file;` ?

`if($file >= 1)` will never be true, as $file is always a String, never an integer, you are comparing there: `if("myfilename.ext" >= 1)`.

To count the total files you should do a while through the full directory and use a counter, increasing it for each file.

Or you can use `scandir("myPath")` function, that get all the files in the path specified as an array. for example:

```
$dir = scandir("myDir");
$total = count($dir); // this gives you the lenght of the array, therefore the files.
```

While counting, remember that the parent, and root directory are counted as "files" as well, and with some methods also the thumbs.db(windows) or DS_store(osx) are hidden files that store information about how you sort the folder, folder icons and stuff, will be counted as well, so remember to add an If statement to skip them.